# rsync delete all source files that are synchronized with destination

Tags: rsync

I'm using `rsync --remove-source-files --ignore-existing src/ me@server:dest/` to upload new files to the remote server without clobbering/updating any existing files.  Any newly uploaded files are removed following this operation.

I would also like files that are already identical on both ends to be removed from `src/`.  That is, the only files remaining in `src/` should be files that were not uploaded because a **different** copy already exists on the server.

Use case: synchronize files from local to server, but 'fail' on operations where a merge conflict exists (manual resolution).  Anything that resolved successfully is removed automatically.

This could be solved with multiple commands if necessary (e.g. existing command to upload, a separate command to find identical files and remove from local)

Answer (score 0):

Excellent question.  rsync is really just used for "one way" mirroring.  For your scenario, consider the use of Unison (see [https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/unison/)) which is a 2-way synchronisation tool.  It can handle conflicts nicely, but if you only want to sync in one way, take a look at the --force or --prefer options.

apt install unison if you're on Ubuntu.